# When is it advantageous to use the L suffix to specify integer quantities in R?

Tags: r, parsing, type-conversion, integer, code-cleanup

Suppose, for example, I have `seek(binfile, 64)`. (When) should this be `seek(binfile, 64L)`, instead? Should I go back through my code base and apply the `L` suffix everywhere I intend integers, but have thus far relied on R to understand what I mean?

Comment: As far as I understand, only if you want to test that they're really integer with `is.integer` for example, or if you have large amounts of them and want to save memory. It also looks tidy for default function arguments and in code in general to to understand faster what type of data one's dealing with

Comment: Thanks to @Moody_Mudskipper for identifying this as a duplicate. May I suggest leaving this page here so that the original question and answers may be found more readily?

Comment: that's exactly how it's supposed to work ;)